# Triger to build pipeline job after successful another 5 jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How to trigger build pipeline job in Jenkins after some successful builds of another 5 jobs? I tried to use Build trigger but it work only for one successful build job, but not for all five of them.

Comment: Are these jobs related to each other in some way?

Comment: These all pipeline jobs belong to one project and exists in one folder in Jenkins UI. That's all.

Comment: You will have to share more info on the system and maybe we can help with another solution